# Architecture used by TikTok and Reels Fan Out on Read vs Fan out on Write

Tags: cassandra, architecture, scalability, distributed-system, system-design

I am trying to build a video timeline for users much like what TikTok or Instagram Reels are doing.

I have following way of handling this :
Fan out on Write :
Create activity feed for each user in Cassandra
Each time a new post is created , I will propagate it to each users feed with a rank in users feed
This way it is always eventually consistent

Currently my users are 300k active , this will grow to 2 million active users , currently am using cassandra data store so that high read and write can be handled, but is this the correct approach ?